# Output the imtId value

Tags: php

Please tell me how to output the `imtId` value, the array is not complete, I will not output further, but the meaning should be clear.Thank you in advance

```
Array
(
    [id] => mavrin-wildberries-1635334576193516728
    [jsonrpc] => 2.0
    [result] => stdClass Object
        (
            [cards] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => d3c33a3f-f5b3-5647-8e7a-ad50d27d4417
                            [imtId] => 30306963
                            [userId] => 0
                            [supplierId] => e9b901b9-b663-5648-97b8-6313d0e245ba
                            [imtSupplierId] => 0
```

I tried:

```
echo ['result']['cards'][0]['nmId']
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: echo ['result']['cards'][0]['nmId']

Comment: Well firstly: you need to echo an actual variable, not just a series of indexes. And the item inside "result" is an object, not an array, and so is the item within the "0" index. And there is no such index as "nmld" - you said you wanted "imtId" instead, so I don't know why you didn't use that? Therefore, if this data is contained in a variable called `$arr` then something like  `echo $arr["result"]->cards[0]->imtId;` should work, I think

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- You need to echo an actual variable, not just a series of indexes.
- The item inside "result" is an object, not an array
- So is the item within the "0" index.
- There is no such index as "nmld" - you said you wanted "imtId" instead, so I don't know why you didn't use that?

Therefore, if this data is contained in a variable called `$arr` then something like

```
echo $arr["result"]->cards[0]->imtId;
```